# Get XML attribute value in bash

Tags: xml, bash

How can I get the `name` attribute name from the `app_name` attribute value?

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">name</string>
    <string name="login">"login"</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: http://www.xmlsh.org/HomePage seems noteworthy.

Comment: Or try http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php